# webpack keeps using default config even when i have a custom webpack.config.js

Tags: css, npm, webpack

I started learning webpack. I am aware that webpack4 doesnt require a configuration explicitly. I created one for my project. On every build i see it picking up default config.
below is my package.json

```
   {
 "name": "feedback-clientlibs",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "build": "webpack"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "hkesani",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
   "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
   "webpack": "^4.43.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "lodash": "^4.17.15"
 }
}
```

and my webpack.config.js is as follows

```
var path = require('path');

module.export ={
    entry : './js/feedback.js',
    mode:'none',
    output : {
        filename:'feedback.js',
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'webpack.modules')
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['css-loader']

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have few css imports into the js files as below

```
import '../css/feedback.css' 
import '../css/all.css'
```

whenever i run a build (i have cssloader installed) below is what i see

```
$ npm run build

> feedback-clientlibs@1.0.0 build C:\projects\br_translation\jcr\code\jcr_root\apps\r\dcloud\components\clientlibs\feedback-clientlibs
> webpack

Hash: 7c51d9af54f992c3e551
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 106ms
Built at: 05/10/2020 10:39:42 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js 6.17 KiB {0} [built]
[1] ./css/feedback.css 302 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[2] ./css/all.css 292 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in ./css/feedback.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #feedback {
|       height: 5em;
|       padding: 10px 22px 8px 22px;
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-28

ERROR in ./css/all.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .ratings-stars {
|       margin-bottom: 15px;
|       height: 13px;
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! feedback-clientlibs@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the feedback-clientlibs@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hkesani\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T17_09_42_363Z-debug.log
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with style-loader?

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader
```

And update your webpack.config.js rules to:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
         'style-loader',
         'css-loader'
     ]
  }
]
```

I also notice you did not supply a production flag for your webpack command I would update that script to run:

```
webpack --mode production -p
```

Then in your output path try a directory name without the period. This may or may not be the reason but it is normally a naming convention to use a dash or underscore for directory names.

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname,'webpack_modules')
```

Comment: its not about the loader. if you observe the output ```path:path.resolve(__dirname,'webpack.modules')``` it should create a new folder as webpack.modules and place the bundled.js in that. but its creating a dist folder and placing in that----> its using the default config rather than the explicit config.

Comment: ah, I see. Ok, I did notice you had an ERROR in ./css/feedback.css 1:0 on your post so I thought maybe you were having loading issues. Have you tried adding a p flag for the webpack command and naming your directory without a dot. This may or may not be the reason but it is convention to name directories with a dash or underscore. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's defined [here][enter link description here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js).

It can also be inspected via node:

const webpack = require('webpack')
new webpack.WebpackOptionsDefaulter()